# Gensim Word2Vec Embedding instead of GloVe TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, word2vec

I am trying to generate text for which I used custom Gensim Word2Vec embedding. I am trying to fit it instead of GloVe embedding.

Code :

```
glove_path = "/content/drive/MyDrive/Dataset/Bangla AI/custom_bangla_embedding.txt"
```

````
BATCH_SIZE = 64 # number of data points to consider to train at a single point of time
LATENT_DIM = 200 # the size of the hidden state/vector
EMBEDDING_DIM = 1000 # size of the word embeddings - comes into various sizes 50, 100 or 200
MAX_VOCAB_SIZE = 30000 # the maximum number of words to consider
VALIDATION_SPLIT = 0.2 # % of validation dataset```
````

class SequenceGenerator():

````
def __init__(self, input_lines, target_lines, max_seq_len=None, max_vocab_size=10000, embedding_dim=200):        
    self.input_lines = input_lines
    self.target_lines = target_lines
    
    self.MAX_SEQ_LEN = max_seq_len
    self.MAX_VOCAB_SIZE = max_vocab_size
    self.EMBEDDING_DIM = embedding_dim


def initialize_embeddings(self):
    
    # load the word embeddings
    self.word2vec = {}
    with open(glove_path%self.EMBEDDING_DIM, 'r') as file:
        for line in file:
            vectors = line.split()
            self.word2vec[vectors[0]] = np.asarray(vectors[1:], dtype="float32")

            
    # get the embeddings matrix
    self.num_words = min(self.MAX_VOCAB_SIZE, len(self.word2idx)+1)
    self.embeddings_matrix = np.zeros((self.num_words, self.EMBEDDING_DIM))
    
    for word, idx in self.word2idx.items():
        if idx <= self.num_words:
            word_embeddings = self.word2vec.get(word)
            if word_embeddings is not None:
                self.embeddings_matrix[idx] = word_embeddings
                
    self.idx2word = {v:k for k,v in self.word2idx.items()}


def prepare_sequences(self, filters=''):
    
    # train the tokenizer
    self.tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=self.MAX_VOCAB_SIZE, filters='')
    self.tokenizer.fit_on_texts(self.input_lines+self.target_lines)
    
    # get the word-index mapping and initialize embeddings
    self.word2idx = self.tokenizer.word_index
    self.initialize_embeddings()
    
    # tokenize the input and target lines
    self.input_sequences = self.tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(self.input_lines)
    self.target_sequences = self.tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(self.target_lines)
    
    # get the max sequence len from the data
    max_seq_len = max(list(map(len, self.input_lines+self.target_lines)))
    if self.MAX_SEQ_LEN:
        self.MAX_SEQ_LEN = min(self.MAX_SEQ_LEN, max_seq_len)
    else:
        self.MAX_SEQ_LEN = max_seq_len
        
    # pad the sequences
    self.input_sequences = pad_sequences(self.input_sequences, maxlen=self.MAX_SEQ_LEN, padding="post")
    self.target_sequences = pad_sequences(self.target_sequences, maxlen=self.MAX_SEQ_LEN, padding="post")
    
    print("1st input sequence: ", self.input_sequences[0])
    print("1st target sequence: ", self.target_sequences[0])
    
    
def one_hot_encoding(self):
    "Creates the One-hot encoding for the target sequence."
    
    # it will be a 3 dimensional array where
    # first-dim is the number of target lines
    # second-dim is the size of the sequences
    # third-dim is the number of words in the dataset
    self.one_hot_targets = np.zeros((len(self.target_sequences), self.MAX_SEQ_LEN, self.num_words))
    
    for seq_idx, seq in enumerate(self.target_sequences):
        for word_idx, word_id in enumerate(self.target_sequences[seq_idx]):
            if word_id > 0:
                self.one_hot_targets[seq_idx, word_idx, word_id] = 1


def get_closest_word(self, word_vec):
    """
        Find the nearest word to the provided vector. The distance between the vectors is 
        calculated using the cosine-distance.
        
        Parameters:
            word_vec (np.array): a vector of size EMBEDDING_DIM
            
        Returns:
            Str: the closest word to the provided vector
    """
    
    max_dist = 9999999999
    closest_word = "NULL"
    
    # iterate overall the words and find the closest one
    for word, vec in self.word2vec.items():
        
        # get the cosine distance between the words
        dist = spatial.distance.cosine(word_vec, vec)
        
        # compare the distance and keep the minimum
        if dist < max_dist:
            max_dist = dist
            closest_word = word
    
    return closest_word```
````

## create an object of the class

````
                           max_vocab_size=MAX_VOCAB_SIZE, embedding_dim=EMBEDDING_DIM)```

# prepare the input & target sequences
```sg_obj.prepare_sequences()```
# create the One-hot encoding on the target sequences
```sg_obj.one_hot_encoding()```

# make sure the tokenized words contains <sos> & <eos>
```assert '<sos>' in sg_obj.word2idx
assert '<eos>' in sg_obj.word2idx```




But getting the following error:
````

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

````
```<ipython-input-36-3edfcb198239> in <module>()
    133 
    134 # prepare the input & target sequences
--> 135 sg_obj.prepare_sequences()
    136 # create the One-hot encoding on the target sequences
    137 sg_obj.one_hot_encoding()```

```1 frames

<ipython-input-36-3edfcb198239> in initialize_embeddings(self)
     29         # load the word embeddings
     30         self.word2vec = {}
---> 31         with open(glove_path%self.EMBEDDING_DIM, 'r') as file:
     32             for line in file:
     33                 vectors = line.split()```

```TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
````

Looking for kind help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you update your question to show the full code you're running that triggers the error, including the value of relevant variables like `glove_path` and `self.EMBEDDING_DIM`?

Answer (score 0):

The `%` operator in Python is for string-formatting via 'interpolation'. It expects the string (its left-side argument) to have a certain format, and the values (its right-side argument) to be a matched sequence (or dict). See:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#old-string-formatting

You're passing this improper arguments, thus hitting this error. Nothing in all your other code has anything to do with the error. For example, this is enough to trigger the exact same error:

```py
>>> glove_path = 'foo'
>>> EMBEDDING_DIM = 1000
>>> glove_path%EMBEDDING_DIM
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

So: don't misuse that `%` on variables with improper values, and you won't get that error. (It appears from context the offending line just seeks to open one specific existing file - so perhaps, just use plain `glove_path`?)